# How to correctly set the path?

Tags: init-file, config

I've been unable to run the elixir shell using `alchemist-iex-run` because the erlang executable `erl` is not found in my path. Here's the error:

```
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/elixir/1.12.1/bin/elixir: line 230: exec: erl: not found
Process Alchemist-IEx exited abnormally with code 127
```

In an attempt to fix this, in init.el I added:

```
(add-to-list 'exec-path "/opt/homebrew/bin")
(add-to-list 'exec-path "/opt/homebrew/sbin")
```

But this still doesn't work. Here's the result from...

vterm `echo $PATH`: Includes the added homebrew paths.

`(exec-path)`:
Includes the added homebrew paths.

`(call-process "ENV" nil t)`:
Does not include the added homebrew paths.

Erlang shell: `os:cmd("echo $PATH").`:
Does not include the added homebrew paths, but includes path to erl at /opt/homebrew/Cellar/erlang/24.0.2_1/lib/erlang/erts-12.0.2/bin.

How to correctly set the path so that the added homebrew paths always appear?

Answer (score 1):

`exec-path` is where *Emacs* looks for executables.  The `PATH` environment variable is... well, an environment variable.

If you want to change the environment that Emacs passes to sub-processes, see the `process-environment` variable and `setenv` function.

See also <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp)System Environment`

I'm extremely surprised if `vterm` is adding `exec-path` to `PATH`.  It's probably considered a feature rather than a bug, but it's not normal.